# Rails - how to search through a big data collection and display them in a few-second-intervals?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ajax, search, geolocation

I have a database of hundreds of thousands records that I fetch from database and counting a geographic distance between these records. The problem is that this search takes like 15 - 20 seconds, so I am trying to speed it up.

I think I can't do more with indexing of columns as I am grabbing the whole database table. The most time consume to count the geographic distance (through longitude and latitude). I don't know if there's a way to speed up this computation.

Because this task is - in my mind - almost the same like searching fly tickets, where you set a "from city" point to a "destination city" point and the search engine will gradually display found results to the user in time interval, like:

- it displays some results
- in line 2 seconds it will add another computed results
- in another 2 seconds another computed results
- and so on

I think this way of displaying results would be the best for my case - however, how this engine works?  How can one make the search that will like every 2 seconds display another and another new results?

As the application is written in Ruby on Rails, for this kind of search would be:

- AJAX
- delayed_job

Possibly something else yet?

Or am I thinking about this problem in a wrong way and is there a better one to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I'll just leave this here. http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: There are many ways on how to solve this... Can you answer this... 1. How do you count the distance? 2. Are you looking for nearest neighbours or are you doing something else? 3. Did you already add some kind of spacial indexes? 4. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: **Oto**, thank you for your message. 1/ I'm using **geokit-rails** - **haversine**. 2/ I am looking for "venues" in a chosen radius (ex. 100 miles). 3/No, nothing yet. 4/ MySQL 5.5.35.